# Pass 'interval' value to date_trunc function in PostgreSQL procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, functions, datetime, plpgsql

I am fetching the **"age"** of **two timestamp columns** (**End and Start**) and further choosing it as **to_char 'MM'** format. So I have the difference of the months from two timestamp columns.

The syntax in the above statement goes like :

```
i = (select to_char(age(End,Start),'MM'));

interval_value = (select i || ' month');
```

**Also tried:** `interval_value = i || '   Month'`

Now,

Passing the value of 'i' in another function **date_trunc** of PostgreSQL.

```
xyz = (select date_trunc('month',Start::date) + interval_value::text::interval);
```

The data types for the above variables are:

```
i numeric :=0

xyz date;

interval_value varchar;
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Is there any alternate approach I could use here. The main idea is to get the difference from two timestamps in months and then further passing the difference into the date_trunc function.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure about your objective, but what you show ***works*** with **legal identifiers**. *"end"* is a [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and I wouldn't use *"start"* either. Reserved words require double-quoting, best avoided to begin with:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
   ts_start       timestamp := '2019-03-20 00:00:00';  -- legal name
   ts_end         timestamp := '2019-07-02 01:12:13';
   i              numeric   := (select to_char(age(ts_end, ts_start),'MM'));
   interval_value varchar   := i || ' month'; 
   xyz            date      := (select date_trunc('month',ts_start::date)
                                     + interval_value::text::interval);
BEGIN
   RAISE NOTICE '%', xyz;
END
$$;
```

Can be *much* simpler, though:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
   ts_start       timestamp := '2019-03-20 00:00:00';
   ts_end         timestamp := '2019-06-29 01:12:13';
   xyz            date      := date_trunc('month', ts_start)
                             + date_trunc('month', age(ts_end, ts_start));
BEGIN
   RAISE NOTICE '%', xyz;
END
$$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=62682332a64e7d8d95177dd218d8c4ab)* (raising exceptions to display the result)